# password regex - raw brace is not allowed in regular expression with unicode flag

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using a jquery plugin bootstrap validator for real-time frontend validations.

When I add a pattern/regex validation to validate a password (any string at least 8 characters long), I get the following error

> Unable to check `<input pattern='^.*{8,}$'>` because the pattern is not a valid regexp: raw brace is not allowed in regular expression with unicode flag

The Html is

```
<input pattern="^.*{8,}$" class="form-control" required="required" name="user[password]" id="user_password" type="password">
```

How should I write the regex ?

Comment: Are you trying to match everything with 8 characters or more?

Comment: A password that is at least 8 characters long. And yes I forgot the whitespace, see @Dekel answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `^.{8,}$` instead.

This regex is valid for any char - 8 times or more.

Note that it will also allow spaces inside the password. If you want to allow any char that is not space, you can use `^[^\s]{8,}$` instead.

Your current regex is actually

> accept any char (`.`) - any number of times (*), and accept it (the "any char any number of times") with at least 8 chars `{8,}` (which makes no sense).

Comment: Thanks, I guess I got mislead by the error message (I was looking for a problem with the curly brace) and didn't realize the problem was somewhere else :D. And thanks for the note.

Comment: The `^` and `$` are not required in the HTML5 pattern attribute.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I'm not sure if the validation is done by the HTML5 or by another validation-plugin which is javascript-based.